# Pointer to an element in QList

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a list of lists container with this type:

```
QList< QList<UAVObject *> > objects;
```

For some reason I would like to access one of the internal lists quickly. Can I store a pointer to an internal list? For example:

```
QList<UAVObject *>& ref = objects[0];
QList<UAVObject *>* pt = &ref;
```

Will the value of `pt` still be valid across different function calls and original `objects` manipulations? Let's assume that the `objects` list will only be added to and never removed from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QList` is not based on a STL container and has nothing to do with `std::list`.
The invalidation rules specified for the STL containers are not applicable.

According to the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html) (and my understanding), it uses an array of pointers to the items, unless the item is not larger than a `void*` and declared as *movable* (with Q_MOVABLE_TYPE).

In that case, the item is directly stored in the array and the reference will become invalid when your list will grow (the array of pointers will be reallocated).

Comment: Ah, that's why they can implement `[]` access in O(1).

Comment: @ilya1725, compared to stl containers, QList is more of a std::deque, that's why there also exists QLinkedList, which is more of a list

Comment: @MasterAler, I did not know that, thank you. Why not call the containers the way they are, i.e. dequeue and list?

Comment: @ilya1725, well, I just guess that this naming desicion comes from some average practice of Qt container's usage -- it's not an often situation when someone _really_ needs a simple linked list, more likely that someone _doesn't want/need_ QVector, complex server backends is not usually written in Qt, after all =). Thus, QList is multipurpose and efficient for average cases, all classes in designed to be used quickly and easily (like QTcpSocket is not as customizable as real socket, but is very straightforward when used). That's my assumption))

Comment: I suggest a very good article about [Qt containers](https://marcmutz.wordpress.com/effective-qt/containers/) by Marc Mutz