# How Qlist handles pointers

Tags: qt, qlist, qvector

Cite to Qt document, I know that:

> QList will allocate its items on the heap unless sizeof(T) <=
>   sizeof(void*) and T has been declared to be either a Q_MOVABLE_TYPE or
>   a Q_PRIMITIVE_TYPE using Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO.

Would you please explain how it handles the pointers? Is there any difference between `Qlist<SomeClass *>` and `Qvector<SomeClass *>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointer to an element in QList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55071969/pointer-to-an-element-in-qlist)

Comment: I suggest a very good article about [Qt containers](https://marcmutz.wordpress.com/effective-qt/containers/) by Marc Mutz

Answer (score 0):

`QList` doesn't *handle* pointers at all.

To `QList` it's just another value type.

Since the size of a raw pointer is by definition `== sizeof(void*)`, its internal memory layout will be similar to that of `QVector`.

Comment: Thanks, Now I have another question. Qt says that prepend for `QList` has constant time complexity. When we define a `QList<SomeClass *>` as you said it will act like `QVector`. Does `QList` prepend operation still takes constant time in such a situation?

Comment: Have a look at the [Algorythmic Complexity](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#algorithmic-complexity) section of the documentation. If you can avoid the prepend and do append instead, use a QVector, ideally with reserve().